# What is the meaning of ValueError in Keras? - 'Tensor conversion requested dtype complex64 for Tensor with dtype float32'

Tags: deep-learning, keras, computer-vision

I have the following part of code -

```
...
model.add(Generic_act_func())
print('layer 1 output')
print(model.layers[1].output) #Here layers[1] is Generic_act_func() layer specified above
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: tf.spectral.irfft2d(x)))
...
```

Which when run produces the following output and error respectively -

Output -

```
layer 1 output
Tensor("generic_act_func_1/Complex:0", shape=(?, 28, 28, 9), dtype=complex64)
```

Error -

```
ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype complex64 for Tensor with dtype float32: 'Tensor("lambda_1/Placeholder:0", shape=(?, 28, 28, 9), dtype=float32)'
at line

model.add(Lambda(lambda x: tf.spectral.irfft2d(x)))
```

tf.spectral.irfft2d() requires a complex64 input which the previous layer i.e., Generic_act_func() layer is already producing (as printed by layer 1 output), hence I am not able to figure out why this error. Thanks in advance for any help for solving the error.

Edit - Could there be a mistake wrt passing previous layer outputs to the Lambda layer? Like I have used a variable 'x' in the Lambda function assuming the previous layer output will be captured in this variable. Is this the correct way of adding the Lambda layer? (I am a beginner in Keras, so will be really grateful for any help)

Comment: Making a separate custom layer rather than using a Lambda layer solved the issue for me. The possible reason according to me might be the use of 'tf.spectral.irfft' function inside the Lambda function. This function changes the output shape which needs to be specified using compute_output_shape.